# Вычисление в SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

Доброго времени суток всем! Написала вот такой код, но почему-то вот эта строка дает не правильный результат:

```
((g.kolvo_got) - (o.kolvo_brak) + isnull(r.v_remonte,0)/g.kolvo_got) as kach
```

Вроде все правильно, не пойму где ошиблась...

```
select d.tip, g.kolvo_got, o.kolvo_brak, 
(g.kolvo_got) - (o.kolvo_brak) as otk, 
(g.kolvo_got) - (o.kolvo_brak) + isnull(r.v_remonte,0) as kol_godn,
((g.kolvo_got) - (o.kolvo_brak) + isnull(r.v_remonte,0)/g.kolvo_got) as kach
from zip_op_def d with(nolock)
inner join @_got g on g.tip = d.tip
inner join @_otk o on o.tip = d.tip and o.tip = g.tip
left join @_rem r on r.tip = d.tip
group by d.tip, g.kolvo_got, o.kolvo_brak, r.v_remonte
```

Comment: Что должно получатся и что получается и при каких исходных данных, опишите по-подробнее, а то из формулы не совсем все понятно.

Comment: tip      kolvo_got kolvo_brak  otk       kol_godn   kach
101002004 1916 729     1187 1187   0
101002003 16055 3094     12961 12961   0
101003001 8777 376     8401 8401   0
101001004 2385 229     2156 2156   0
101001002 9399 191     9208 9208   0
101001003 101386 1501     99885 99885   0


Мне нужно вычислить качество путем kol_godn/kolvo_got, например для первой строки 1187/1916 = 0,619...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у вас все аргументы целочисленные, поэтому и результат получается целочисленным. преобразуйте либо делимое, либо делитель в вещественное число. проще всего - умножить на вещественную единицу

```
../(g.kolvo_got*1.0)
```

Comment: попробую :)

Answer (score 2):

```
( (g.kolvo_got) - (o.kolvo_brak) + isnull(r.v_remonte,0)/g.kolvo_got  ) as kach
```

Как я понял- вы не поставили ещё одни скобки:

```
( ( (g.kolvo_got) - (o.kolvo_brak) + isnull(r.v_remonte,0) ) / g.kolvo_got ) as kach
```

Comment: добавила скобки, получается 0 :(

Comment: Может вы как-то странно добавили, т.к. результат должен быть не такой...

Comment: Уже и так пробовала( ( (g.kolvo_got) - (o.kolvo_brak) + isnull(r.v_remonte,0) ) / (g.kolvo_got)) as kach   
все равно 0

Comment: Удивительно) Тогда больше версий нету....

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, выражение по хорошему должно выглядеть так

```
CASE
    WHEN ISNULL( g.kolvo_got,0 ) = 0 THEN 0 
    ELSE ( ISNULL(g.kolvo_got,0) - ISNULL(o.kolvo_brak,0) + ISNULL(r.v_remonte,0) )  \ISNULL( g.kolvo_got,0 ) 
END as kach
```

ибо любые действия с null будут давать null и деление на ноль будет давать ошибку при вычислениях